# Error "Connection must be valid and open." al conectar c# con MySql

Tags: mysql, c#

Este código solo lista las bases de datos que existe, cuando compilo e ingreso los datos correctamente me aparece este error:

> Connection must be valid and open.

Al intentar conectar *C#* con *MySQL* en la línea `reader = comando.ExecuteReader();`, no encuentro la solución a mi problema.

```
private void bingresar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String usuario = tusuario.Text;
            String password = tpassword.Text;
            String db = "mysql";
            String server = "localhost";
            String puerto = "3306";

            String conexion = "Database=" + db + "; Data Source=" + server + "; Port=" + puerto + "; User Id=" + usuario + "; Password=" + password;
            
            MySqlConnection conexionbd = new MySqlConnection(conexion);
            MySqlDataReader reader;
            String data = null;
            try
            {
                
                String consulta = "SHOW DATABASES";
                MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(consulta);
                conexionbd.Open();
                reader = comando.ExecuteReader();//aqui me sale el error
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    data += reader.GetString(0)+ "\n";
                }
                MessageBox.Show(data);
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error: " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                conexionbd.Close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas pasarle la conexión que acabas de crear al comando:

```
MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(consulta,conexionbd);
```